# Create a range of users using ASP.Net Identity

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-identity

I'm looking for the fastest way to create a range of users in asp.net, the CreateUser in UserManager of ASP.Net commit transaction each time, so it's too slow to adding 10000 user

also adding directly using context is not possible because of some fields that identity controller like Password field

is there any solution to add range then save changes?

Comment: If it helps: [`UserStore` code](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetIdentity/blob/main/src/Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework/UserStore.cs#L410-L419) and [`UserManager` code](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetIdentity/blob/main/src/Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Core/UserManager.cs#L363-L378)

Comment: do you have direct use of the database, and perhaps the web auth provider is in a database table? You can hit that database directly - but you ALSO have to add rows to the roles provider table.  it depends on where the database for the user resides, but for a one time import you could by-pass the web methods provided by asp.net, and add the data directly to the security tables in question.